# Taking long strides, he covered the distance in short time ( gerund or participle)

Tags: gerunds-vs-participles

> Taking long strides, he covered the distance in short time.

*Taking long strides* is a gerund or participle? Explain please.

Comment: In traditional grammar it's called a present participle. Note that it is a supplementary adjunct, not the subject of the sentence.

Comment: The ending "... in short time" is awkwardly phrased. Better: "... in little time." Or even better: "... very quickly."